# Not able to change the End point URL in APIMan to public IP

Tags: api-gateway, apiman

We are trying to configure APIMan on Aws server. We were able to publish API as public and endpoint also, working fine & fetching the results with backend API.
default end point is something like,

> https://localhost:8443/apiman-gateway/XXX/XX/1.0

But we want to access those api's over the internet. So instead of localhost want to give public ip in End point configuration but it is not at all connecting to that public IP.

[image]

As this didn't worked we have tried with URL Rewrite plugin available but even that is not giving any proper results.